# How to calculate which independant variable influences dependant variable the most?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. All my variables are continous including the dependent variable. Is there a way i can calculate which of my independent variables influences my dependent variable the most in python? Is there an algorithm i could ran to do this for me?

i tried the information gain method but that was a classification method so had to use a labelencoder to transform my dependent variable. I used the following code after splitting my dataset into a train and test set

```
#encoding the dependant variable
lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
training_scores_encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(y_train)

#SelectFromModel will select those features which importance is greater than the mean importance of all the features by default, but we can alter this threshold if we want.
#Firstly, I specify the random forest instance, indicating the number of trees.
#Then I use selectFromModel object from sklearn to automatically select the features.
sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100))
sel.fit(X_train, training_scores_encoded)

#We can now make a list and count the selected features.    
selected_feat= X_train.columns[(sel.get_support())]
len(selected_feat)

#viewing the importances 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
importances = sel.estimator_.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
# X is the train data used to fit the model 
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X_train.shape[1]), importances[indices],
       color="r", align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X_train.shape[1]), indices)
plt.xlim([-1, X_train.shape[1]])
```

Although i got a result, I'm not sure about this because i had to encode my (continous) dependent variable. Is this correct way to go? if not what can i do?

Thank you in advance for the assitance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SelectKBest` class from `scikit-learn` module.

Check the original documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.fit).

This technique is called Feature Selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pick features with the highest correlation to the response.

```
print([(feature, abs(df[response].corr(df[feature]))) for feature in features])
```

This uses values from Tamarie's comment.

```
for feature in feature_cols:
    print(f'feature: {feature} correlation: {abs(target_v.corr(df[feature]))}')
```

Comment: can you show me an examole of this? what is feature and response in this case?

Comment: A feature is an individual measurable property or characteristic of a phenomenon being observed. In other words: all columns except the target column. And the response is exactly the targer column.